# Помогите пожалуйста сделать блок схему

Tags: visual-basic

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мне нужно сделать блок схему по коду Visual Basic.

```
Public Class Form1
Public Function fact(n As Integer) As Long
    Dim x As Integer, i As Integer
    x = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        x *= i
    Next
    fact = x

End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Label1.Text = fact(Val(TextBox1.Text))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Что не понятно может быть по блосхемам? Присвоение - прямоугольник, условие - ромб. Цикл - шестиугольник

Comment: Я не знаю VB, поэтому сложно

Comment: Сделайте пожалуйста, или проверьте что у меня получилось

Comment: Цикл - шестиугольник (вместо ромба). Сайт предполагает что базу языка учасники знают. Не знаю VB - тут не аргумент.